# getting DesignTimeDbContextFactory to run migrations without executing Startup

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my ASP.Net core application, Startup class has many things that is not needed to do migrations. According to [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design.idesigntimedbcontextfactory-1?view=efcore-5.0) it seems I can create a DesignTimeFactory which will prepare the specified context and use it for migration purposes.

So I have created the simple class implementing IDesignTimeDbContextFactory which will simply accept a parameter, do some work with it and then return the MigrationContext for rest of the work within CreateDbContext(string[] args).

My problem is when I run Add-Migration commands from the console, it still executes StartUp class. . I thought with DesignTimeFactory, it shouldn't try to wire-up everything but simply use the context returned by the factory and use it for migration purposes.

Is there a way to avoid executing Startup class

```
       public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                Debugger.Launch();
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

and simply rely only on the DBContextFactory for migration? So Startup class is only executing at run time

Comment: Probably something is wrong with your class implementing `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` which prevents EF Core finding/using it. Run `Add-Migration` with `-Verbose` option and see/post the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this has been in discussion at various levels. See [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/9076)

So basically I renamed the **CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)** method name to **PrepareHostBuilder(string[] args)** and DesignTimeFactory stopped trying to wireup Startup stuff.

In the above URL, there is a detailed discussion going on about this.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [EF cli supports command line arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=vs#from-a-design-time-factory), a hack-ish work around is to pass in an arg of some kind to the Add-Migration or Update-Database command and check for its existence in the CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) method:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        if (!args.Contains("design"))
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

And then you could call the following command in PackageManagerConsole to skip the Startup file:

```
PM> Update-Database -Context MyContext -Args "design"
```